# Mongoose: querying a nested array with findOne() and projecting out

Tags: mongoose

I have a collection Cities with documents in the following structure:

```
city = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b9eac23cad92dbd81f92b"),
    "stores" : [
        {
            "name" : "someName",
            "storeId" : "5b9350dc97c35614731e03df"
        }
     ]
}
```

How do I query the collection Cities by storeId, and get the city object in Mongoose using findOne()?

I've tried the following ways, but in both I'm getting 'null'

```
query = {
   'stores.storeId' : someId
}

query = {
   'stores': {'$elemMatch': {'storeId': someId}}
}

Cities.findOne(query)
.then( city => {
   console.log('city: '+ city);
});
```

Then I was trying to project out only the name.
I thought about using:

```
options = {
   select: { 'stores.$.name': 1 }
}

Cities.findOne(query, {}, options)
.then( name => {
   console.log('name: '+ name);
});
```

But I'm clueless if it will work, since I have not even succeeded in querying it...

Comment: The above should work. What's the trouble?

Comment: I don't now.. It's just returning "null". 
When I test on mongo shell, it works. On Mongoose, not working.

Comment: I've found out the error! ...In the database, storeId was saved as a String instead of an ObjectId, but in the schema it was set as mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId. When I changed the schema to String, the document was found.

Comment: @JoãoOtero Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error:
...In the database, storeId was saved as a String instead of an ObjectId, but in the schema it was set as mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId. When I changed the schema to String, the document was found.